# How do match a string with text patterns in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, regex

I have something like:

```
<a href="Pages/MyLink_1_02.php" class="Style8">Text 1</a><br>
<a href="Pages/MyLink_1_03.php" class="Style8">Text 2</a><br>
```

How can I find all `Pages/MyLink_[NUM]_[NUM]`?

So far I have:`linksText.match(/\"Pages/MyLink_"/)` but that's way off. Ideas?

Comment: Try learning how to regex? You don't appear to have made any legitimate attempt here...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var regex = /Pages\/MyLink_(\d+)_(\d+)/g,
    match;
while ((match = regex.exec(data)) !== null) {
    console.log("Actual match ", match[0]);
    console.log("First number ", match[1]);
    console.log("Second number", match[2]);
}
```

**Output**

```
Actual match  Pages/MyLink_1_02
First number  1
Second number 02
Actual match  Pages/MyLink_1_03
First number  1
Second number 03
```

[Online Demo 1, with explanation of the RegEx](http://regex101.com/r/qI0uA6)

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/SOW4SS3n5z5-GCio)

Answer (score 2):

Replace `[NUM]` with `(\d+)`. That will do it.

```
/Pages\/MyLink_(\d+)_(\d+)\.php/
```

You can get the numbers like this:

```
var regex = /Pages\/MyLink_(\d+)_(\d+)\.php/;
var str = "Pages/MyLink_1_02.php";
var arr = str.replace(regex,"$1,$2").split(",");
```

`arr[0]` will contain the first number, while `arr[1]` will contain second number.

Comment: should be `\.php`, not `.php`, because `.` means "any symbol"